# Notepad++ RegEx Escape-to-Plaintext Character List

Tags: regex, ascii, notepad++

In N++ RegEx, which ASCII (32-127,128-254) characters *need* to be escaped into to display as plain text, and which optionally *can* be escaped into?

Specifically, am I right in guessing that:

- every numeral, upper-case letter and lower-case letter, when escaped, is interpreted as a control code, and
- every other character, when escaped, is interpreted as itself, whether or not it has a syntactic function

Comment: I think your question is *off topic*, because it is not about programming ;).

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be: Yes, except for < and >.

\< looks to mean "Insert one character to the left of any alphanumeric character, excluding whitespace". > is "Insert at rightward word boundaries".